# Size of class derived from multiple inherited class with virtual function

Tags: c++, codeblocks, virtual-inheritance, diamond-problem

Consider the diamond scenario below:

```
class Base {
    int x;
public:
    virtual ~Base(){}
};

class Derived1 : virtual public Base {
    int y;
};

class Derived2 : virtual public Base {
    int z;
};

class Derived3 : public Derived1, public Derived2 {
    int t;
};
```

- Size of **Base** is **8** [*x(4) + vptr(4) (from virtual destructor)*]
- Size of **Derived1** is **16** [*x(4) + y(4) + vptr(4) (from virtual destructor) + vptr(4) (from virtual inheritance)*]
- Size of **Derived2** is **16** [*x(4) + z(4) + vptr(4) (from virtual destructor) + vptr(4) (from virtual inheritance)*]
- Size of **Derived3** is **28** [*x(4) + y(4) + z(4) + t(4) + vptr(4) (from virtual destructor) + 2 times vptr(4) (from virtual inheritance of Derived1 and Derived2)*]

Now, if I add another class **Derived4** which derives from **Derived 3**,

```
class Derived4 : public Derived3 {
    int s;
};
```

it's size comes out to be **32** (which I'm assuming to be **size of Derived3 + s**).

I want to know if there is no virtual pointer inside **Derived4**?

If I take a normal class hierarchy (without diamond structure), then if a base class has a virtual function, then all derived classes have vptrs. So, why not in this case?

I'm compiling the code in codeBlocks 12.11 with GNU GCC compiler.

Comment: [Mandatory reading](http://www.phpcompiler.org/articles/virtualinheritance.html).

Answer (score 0):

Since Derived4 has not added any virtual functions or virtual base classes, beyond what it has inherited from Derived3, the only increase in size is for the member s.

Comment: AFAIK, there is a vtable created for every derived class if the base class has a virtual function, no matter how many levels of hierarchy are present. And, if it has a vtable, it should have a vptr. Is this understanding incorrect?